# Loop on loading images, one by one, only after previous has been fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, load

As the title suggests, I have a list of images that I want loaded. I have a function that given a numerical value from 1 to 1000 (approx.) changes the source of the image object in my html document to be the desired image name. This numerical value is kept in a global variable, which may change at times, and then, by calling that function, the actual image src will change as well.

For example:

```
if ( myImage == 1)
    document.getElementById("mainImage").src = "snow.bmp";
else if ( myImage == 2)
    document.getElementById("mainImage").src = "desert.bmp";
else if ( myImage == 3)
    document.getElementById("mainImage").src = "forest.bmp";
```

And so on. I know, this can be done in a better looking way, rather than using `if-else` every time, but that's not my current issue.

What I noticed is that every image takes some time to load during my main `index.html` when placed on remote servers (locally it loads fast), so in order to overcome this, I wanted to preload all the images, with a nice advancement bar on the side or some numerical track.

To do so, I created a separate html, that will be some sort of an intro. I want to iterate over all possible numerical values, lets say, ranging `1` to `1000`. Each time, updating `myImage` to be that value. After a value is assigned to `myImage`, the function `makeImage()`, which is the `if-else` from above, is called. Then, the actual source of  `mainImage` is changed accordingly. This completes a single iteration. **Only after the image is loaded to the user**, do I want to move to the next value in the range `[1,1000]`. I tried reading online about `wait` and `async` and promises, but could not bring to implement this for my case.

So far my code is built of the main method to load:

```
async function loadAllImages()
            {
                for(var valueOfCell = 1; valueOfCell <= 1000; valueOfCell ++)
                {
                    myImage = valueOfCell;
                    makeImage();
                    let loadedImage = await loadImage();
                }
            }
```

And the waiting function is:

```
function loadImage() {
                const img = new Image();
            
            
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  img.addEventListener("load", () => {
                    resolve();
                  });
            
                  img.addEventListener("error", () => {
                    reject();
                  });
            
                  img.src = document.getElementById("mainImage").src;
                });
            }
```

One of the problems is, I am using an `Image` object, which, to be honest, I have no use in. I might as well say that the above code is combined from stuff I found online, I just wasn't sure how to use `await`.

I would be very glad if someone could assist me in this, especially to understand the usage of `await` and how to use it for my case.

Comment: Not related to JS question but I have noticed you are using BMP images. [BMP format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats#BMP) is uncompressed, so images are huge. You could [convert to PNG](https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-BMP-to-JPEG-Using-Microsoft-Paint), for example, to reduce size and load time.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll do that @Vitalii.